# javascript: Define reference in nested object to parent object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have following object:

```
var myObject = {
    attributes: { name: "dev.pus", age: 29 },
    someInjectedObject: {
        name: "someComponent",
        action: function() {
            // do something
            return this.this.attributes.name; // this surely won't work :(
        }
    }
};
```

As you see I want to get myObject.attributes.name from an nested part of the object without having to observe the value.

How do I do this? How do I define a reference?

**EDIT:**
A simple myObject.attributes isn't enough because myObject changes or better gets assigned to a new variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulate super in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032566/emulate-super-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a closure around your object:

```
var myObject = (function() {
  var result = {
    attributes: { name: "dev.pus", age: 29 },
    someInjectedObject: {
      name: "someComponent",
      action: function() {
        // do something
        return result.attributes.name;
      }
    };
  };
  return result;
})();
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. You shouldn't downvote answers if you change your question.

Comment: Hmm, this would be a possible solution but hard to integrate (I would have to rewright all my Backbone.Model implementations. Maybe there will come another answer. PS: I didn't downvote...

Comment: @dev.pus Instead of creating new closure you can simply create a copy of myObject variable that wouldn't change. This is ugly, but would work. P.S. Sorry for suspecting you :)

Comment: Hmm, I will wait a bit with the final answer mark but it seems that I will have to refactor a lot using closures :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do refer to `myObject` directly like this:

```
var myObject = {
    attributes: { name: "dev.pus", age: 29 },
    someInjectedObject: {
        name: "someComponent",
        action: function() {
            // do something
            return myObject.attributes.name; // this surely will work :(
        }
    }
};

alert(myObject.someInjectedObject.action());
​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qQWk/)

​

Comment: He says in his question that *As you see I want to get `myObject.attributes.name` from an nested part of the object without having to observe the value.* I guess he wouldn't even ask this question if this solution was acceptable