# JavaScript Inheritance of arguments

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do some inheritance in JavaScript

etc

```
var operation = 
{
   A: 1,
   B: 2,
   C: 3
};

var operationImplA = 
{
   D: 4
};

var operationImplB = 
{
   D: function (event) {
         //do something
      }
};
```

Something similar to the above but not sure how to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: There are actually several ways to achieve this. I would suggest you read [this article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) by Douglas Crockford. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7486825/464709).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: You mean that article where at the bottom he acknowledges his attempts to support a classical inheritance model were a mistake?

Comment: @thesystem, absolutely, his conclusion is also valuable information IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `Object.create`:

```
var operation = 
{
   A: 1,
   B: 2,
   C: 3
};

var operationImplA = Object.create(operation, {
    D: {
       value: 4
    }
});

var operationImplB = Object.create(operationImplA, {
    D: {
        value: 5
    }
});
```

`Object.create` will create new object with prototype it's first argument and properties defined in the second argument.

This is the natural prototype-based inheritance in JavaScript.

**Edit**

If you want to add a method, add it like a property i.e.:

```
var operationImplA = Object.create(operation, {
    M: {
        value: function (a) {
            console.log(a);
        }
    }
});
operationImplA.M('Some text...'); //'Some text...'
```

Comment: if I wanted to add a function etc function AA(A, B) {}; How would I do this? In the inherited obj. Tnks!!

Comment: Just like a usual property: func: { value: function () {} }

Answer (score -1):

Personally I really like John Resigs [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). I use it for all my JS projects. You should try it out.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to create a class. He just wants one object to inherit from another.