# Proper inheritance for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

In C#, inheritance is as easy as:

```
class Animal {
    string name;

    public Animal() { }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    public Dog() : base() {
        this.name = "Dog";
    }
}
```

In node.js, I want to have two files (animal.js and dog.js) replicate the above setup while being as simple and non-hacky as possible.

Is this even possible with node.js? If it matters, I'd like to do all this so that I can pass the Animal type through a function without checking the subclass as there will be dozens of classes inheriting the Animal class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486825/javascript-inheritance)

Comment: You could look into writing your NodeJS apps via [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) if you're a C# fanboy.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+inheritance+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @Marty: TypeScript looks amazing, please post that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Typescript tries to follow ecma 6 which will be class based. It has good tooling as well (better than most js toolls ) if you want to know about JavaScript prototype maybe this answer can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 it isn't that hard to understand once you wrap your head around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to mark Marty for the answer but it doesn't look like he's going to. I tried out [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) and it was exactly what I wanted, I didn't have to deal with all the inheritance headaches that plague Javascript (prototyping, etc.)

Just as a pro-tip to anyone that finds this answer, don't forget to grab the type definitions for middleware when using TypeScript. [You can find them here.](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) Don't forget to add the references into your .ts files (for example: `///<reference path='node/node.d.ts' />`).

Comment: Prototypes are not a headache, the are the fundamental basic for inheritance. Your typescript does use them as well.

Comment: @Scott Yeh, it's definitely worth taking at least a peek at the generated code. IIRC, the typescript way translates to quite a lot of boilerplate in the longhand javascript. TypeScript is pretty rocking though... roll on generators and better support for Promises. You might also enjoy taking a peek at google's (experimental) traceur project. You can bootstrap the compiler directly in your own page which eliminates the need for pre-compilation. https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#classes

Comment: I'm glad you invested enough time even to find the definitions for existing libraries :-)